# Migrate videos from SharePoint document library to Microsoft Stream

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, migration, media-streaming

We have many videos stored in SharePoint document libraries, and we want to move them to Microsoft Stream. So is there a way to migrate the videos from SharePoint to Microsoft Stream? Without having to download them from SharePoint and then re-upload them to Stream?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such way to migrate the videos from SharePoint to Microsft Stream, the current feasible way is downloading from SharePoint and upload to Microsoft Stream.

It is worth mentioning that in the new Stream, when you upload videos, they are automatically stored in the SharePoint file platform rather than stored in streams separately, thus strengthening the connection between Stream and other Microsoft 365 applications.

Please note that the migration from Microsoft Stream (classic) to the new Microsoft Stream is still in the early stage.

More information:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/stream/streamnew/new-stream#frequently-asked-questions

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/stream/streamnew/classic-migration